# What values will the WMI Win32_DiskDrive call provide when PC is using hybrid drive?

Tags: hard-drive, wmi, hybrid-storage

When I call the Get-WMIOBject Win32_DiskDrive call I get the following response for a regular drive:
Partitions : 5
DeviceID : \.\PHYSICALDRIVE0
Model : C400-MTFDDAT128MAM
Size : 128034708480
Caption : C400-MTFDDAT128MAM

Anyone can answer what would the response look like for a hybrid drive with 16gb or similar of cache?

Would it report 2 drives, ignore the 16GB cache or add it to the overall size?

Thank you